# Set Image Size and Page Orientation When Exporting to PDF

Tags: export, pdf-format

I want to export my plots (plot1 and plot2) as a pdf file. Since `plot1` contains 4 figures in matrix form, so it will not fit in one page.

`Export["plot.pdf", CreateDocument[Riffle[{plot1, plot2}, 
   Cell["", "PageBreak", PageBreakBelow -> True]], Visible -> False]]`

**Here are my 2 questions:**

**1. How can I control the page layouts (e.g., landscape) when exporting to pdf file ?**

**2. Do we have to set the `imagesize` by ourselves all the time to make figures fit in one page ?**